# What are the possible options for the --arch option in debootstrap?

Tags: 64bit, cpu-architecture, debootstrap

I need to set the arch option in debootstrap. So I did some research and read the manual.

After reading the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/debootstrap) I see that the section on the options simply says 
--arch=ARCH 
Implying that I should know the correct syntax for the architecture I need.
I don't. I need 64 bit architecture.
I know that "i386" can be used for 32bit architecture.
What should I set the --arch option to if I want 64 bit architecture?
Or more generally what would the range of options be?

I could guess (but don't know and can't determine) that potentially the range or arch options depends on the OS being booted. In my case its a version of ubuntu that I know should work in 64bit. So the question becomes how would I determine the 64bit architecture option syntax?

I could further guess (but again don't know and can't determine) that the option syntaxes are actually supplied by the booted OS and if I knew where to look I could figure it out. In which case, where would I look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The possible values are the codenames of the architectures supported by the target operating system. For Ubuntu, check the architectures for which [the C library](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc) is built: for 64-bit x86, the appropriate value is `amd64`.

On systems with `dpkg`,

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

will show the current architecture (which is the default architecture for `debootstrap`).

`debootstrap` is also capable of installing a system for any supported architecture, not only the host system’s architecture; see its `--foreign` option. If necessary it can use Qemu to emulate the target architecture.

Comment: Great thanks! I note also that it is case sensitive and thus AMD64 is NOT correct in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they are those named in the [List of official ports](https://www.debian.org/ports/#portlist-released):

```
amd64       64-bit PC (amd64)
arm64       64-bit ARM (AArch64)
armel       EABI ARM
armhf       Hard Float ABI ARM
i386        32-bit PC (i386)
mips64el    MIPS (64-bit little-endian mode)
ppc64el     POWER7+, POWER8
riscv64     RISC-V (64-bit little endian)
s390x       System z
```

There's another list in the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SupportedArchitectures).